# problema al implementar el ecommerce de la gema Solidus de ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Buen día estoy aprendiendo un poco sobre ruby on rails y quería probar un proyecto open source llamado solidus para la creación rápida de ecommerce, acá lo pueden encontrar https://github.com/solidusio/solidus. Sucede que estoy haciendo la instalación como indica en la documentación(versiones superiores a 2.11 de Solidus), y me arroja el siguiente error. [![aparentemente es un problema con la autentificacion][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqYXr.png

quisiera saber cómo podría solucionarlo. he visto algunos métodos, pero no me han resultado muy útiles. Utiliza una base de datos PostgreSQL, ruby versión 2.5.8 y versión de ruby on rails 6.3.3. Cualquier recomendación será bien recibida.

el archivo database.yml es el siguiente:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: trybuy_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
  username: trybuy

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  password: password

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: trybuy_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: trybuy_production
  username: trybuy
  password: <%= ENV['TRYBUY_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

**el archivo Gemfile es el siguiente:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

gem 'solidus'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'solidus_paypal_commerce_platform'
```

Comment: ¿has verificado que ese usuario `trybuy` esté efectivamente creado en tu bd y con la contraseña `password`? Igual si describes en la pregunta cuales son esos "métodos" que has probado, ayudas a que podamos ayudarte mejor. Te recomiendo que veas alguna guía básica de como configurar rails con postgresql, porque si no me equivoco, es la 2da pregunta que has hecho relacionado con conectarte a la BD (que por cierto, borraste la pregunta en vez de decir si pudiste resolver tu problema, aparte del cómo) y que lo más seguro, es que siquiera tenga relación alguna con el uso de `solidus`. Saludos

Comment: vale gracias voy a mirar esa parte con la base de datos, y pues la primera era un problema más bien con el puerto y lo solucione y consideré borrarla. entonces según me dices es algo con la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

En tu database.yml comenta los valores de "username" y "password". Asi agarra los que son por default o ingresa los valores correspondientes. Ahi mismo en los comentarios del .yml te explica lo que es cada valor.